# Аннотация по условию

Tags: python, django, queryset

У меня есть модель `Dialog`, `Message` и `User`. `DialogPartaker` хранит дату последнего посещения пользователем текущего диалога:

```
class DialogPartaker(models.Model):
    User= models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='talks')
    Dialog = models.ForeignKey('Dialog', related_name='talk')
    Time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Модели `User` и `Dialog` связаны через нее:

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    Partakers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="DialogPartaker")
```

По задумке все сообщения, которые поступили в диалог по прошествии `DialogPartaker.Time` для текущего пользователя являются непрочитанными. Есть вью, которая выводит список диалогов текущего пользователя:

```
qs = Dialog.objects.filter(Partakers__in=[self.request.user])
```

Как можно получить в этом же запросе (например, через аннотации) количество непрочитанных сообщения для текущего пользователя?

Саму дату у меня выдернуть получилось через OuterRef:

```
myLastTime = DialogPartaker.objects.filter(User_id=self.request.user.id).filter(Dialog=OuterRef('id')).values('Time')[:1]
qs.annotate(visit=Subquery(myLastTime))
```

Но как сделать условный запрос через Count к Message никак в голову не идет. Далее задача вытянуть правильно количество непрочитанных сообщений.

Сам Messages выглядит так:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    Time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)                                      
    #...
    Target = models.ForeignKey(Dialog, related_name='messages', related_query_name="messages")
```

Допустим, через тот же subquery:  Хочется сделать какое-то условие на Count, что-то типа `qs.annotate(Count(F(visit)<F('Time')))`. Но ругается на `visit net defined` либо 'Count' object is not iterable. Пробовал так же:

```
lastMessages = Message.objects.annotate(lstTime=Subquery(myLastTime)).filter(lstTime__lt=time).count()
```

> Получаю expected string or buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для условных запросов есть [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)
Если взять за основу ваш вариант с `Subquery` для получения даты последнего посещения пользователем текущего диалога, то получится следующее:

```
from django.db.models import F, OuterRef, Subquery, Sum, Case, When, Value, IntegerField

        myLastTime = (
            DialogPartaker
            .objects
            .filter(User_id=self.request.user.id)
            .filter(Dialog=OuterRef('id'))
            .values('Time')[:1]
        )

        qs = (
            Dialog
            .objects
            .filter(Partakers__in=[self.request.user])
            .annotate(visit=Subquery(myLastTime))
            .annotate(unread=Sum(
                Case(
                    When(messages__Time__gt=F('visit'), then=Value(1)),
                    default=Value(0),
                    output_field=IntegerField(),
                )
            ))
        )
```

P.S. CamelCase не приветствуется.

Comment: Спасибо, это работает удивительно быстро.